# AMD GPU Pro on Loki (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: graphic-drivers, ubuntu, release-loki, amd

I have R9 380 Tonga Chipset which is one of the GPUs AMD GPU Pro supports and since Loki is powered by 16.04 I thought it would work no problem.

I was following the guide from the AMD website 
http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

When I got to the install part I got "Unsupported OS".

I am a new low tier PC consumer to Linux.  Do y'all know a way I can get this to work?  Maybe Cassidy James has some other paternal barrier that I haven't by passed yet?

Comment: I am guessing CIK support is not enabled?

Comment: i tried aswell without success, it does work on stock ubuntu 16.04(unity)

Comment: i have the same problem, is there any suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the following file: `amdgpu-pro-install`

on line 74: (it is 74 for me)

```
#   os_release
```

add that hashtag # to os_release
that calls a function to check for your system type (as far as I understand it)

Add the following line:

```
PACKAGES="amdgpu-pro amdgpu-pro-lib32 amdgpu-pro-dkms"
```

That is all that function did in case the system was Ubuntu or a derivative,
so I just copied it from above.

That part of your file should now look more or less like this:

```
function amdgpu_pro_install() {
    local src=$(cd ${0%/*} && pwd -P)
    local index=$src/Packages.gz

#   os_release
    PACKAGES="amdgpu-pro amdgpu-pro-lib32 amdgpu-pro-dkms"
    amdgpu_pro_uninstall $@

    if [[ -r $index ]]; then
        $SUDO mkdir -p $REPOSITORY && $SUDO cp -af $src/* $_
        $SUDO ln -s $_/$PROG $SBIN/${PROG%-*}-uninstall

        echo "deb file:$REPOSITORY/ ./" | $SUDO tee $(source_list)
        $SUDO apt-get update ||:
        $SUDO apt-get $@ install $PACKAGES
    fi
}
```

Now the driver will install (it did for me). I cannot guarantee that the driver will install correctly and your computer will work fine after doing this.
Consider that this may crash your system before attempting, and you may have to uninstall the driver in a terminal.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use the deb generator it won't work because the script from AMD won't recognize eOS as a derivation of Ubuntu. 
I think you were able to build the deb file via command line and just preset the options.